# Send page control from Liberty application to WebSphere application with custom header

Tags: javascript, ajax, httprequest, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

We have the requirement to call application A deployed in WebSphere Application Server from Application B deployed in WebSphere Liberty with Custom header. Both servers are in same domain but different host. I cannot use `reponse.sendRedirect()` and `window.location`, as they will create a new request. `RequestDispatcher.forward` is used for local resources.

For example,
I have application: https://host1.domain.com/LibertyApp1/index.jsp

This loads a JavaScript in which I need to call WasApp1 in host2.domain.com.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function callWAS(token) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var path = "https://host2.domain.com/WasApp1/SimpleServlet";
    request.open("POST",path,true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization",token);
    request.send(null);
}
```

token is the String which I need to set in the Authorization header.

When the JavaScript is executed it is creating a pre-flight request and both `POST` and `OPTIONS` requests are giving status 200. But the page control is still with LibertyApp1. I want the page control to be with WasApp1. Is there a way by which I can forward the request to WasApp1 with customised http request header?